# Parallel tasks in python

Tags: python

I have a project in which there are three classes, two of them scan the network for anomalies and when the anomaly occur they feed them to a analyzing class.

```
class Scanner1():
    def scan(self):
       #do some scaning
       if True:
          Analyze.analyze(event)`
class Scanner2():
    def scan(self):
       #do some scaning
       if True:
          Analyze.analyze(event)
class Analyze():
    def analyze(self,event):
       #process event
```

I need all classes to run parellel but I am relatively new to python and I wasn't able to find any good way to make it work. I tried some threads but that didn't work. So I wanted to know if there is some to do it.

Comment: Provide your threading-based attempt, please

Comment: "I tried some threads but that didn't work": please explain.  Presumably you have code to back this up?

Comment: How do you want to communicate between the running threads? Do you want to use message passing or shared memory or smth else?

Comment: We don't just give out complete implementations. Understand that doing this himework for you costs us time as well. People here expect you to pull your own weight, which is why we expect you to post the code you have tried so far, so we can tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking forward to is multiprocessing and threading. You should consider this module https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html . 
Also you can look at this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm .